# What is this connector locking clips and where to find it?

Tags: laptop, case, cable, enclosure

I have just purchase the HP Elitebook 8570w and disassemble it for cleaning. Unfortunately when I was trying to put it back I broke all three clips locking cables connection touch-pad and fingerprint-scanner to the motherboard. Well, now I know at least that I was never suppose to pull them out, but thats one other story.

I try to look for exchange parts but I guess my English terminology lacks when it comes to hardware. So I am left with those questions:

- How do you call this type of clip?
- Is this some kind of universal part or am I on the mercy of the laptop manufacturer?

One picture is worth a thousand words, so those are clips locking all three cables right bellow the gpu unit:

[image]